# How to add exception to a dictionary if the result is useless for my data?

Tags: python, django

So I have this code to get the id of a person and check if the person exists in a database. The code works but I forgot to add an exception for people who exist but their id is not a "useful" one.
I tried adding an exception to my code that says:

```
except cuit == "CUIL":
           print("it's not a cuit")
```

But this is ignored and I get the data anyway even though I don't want it. So what's a better way of doing it?
The info is in

```
response["persona"]["tipoClave"]
```

This gives two results: "CUIL" (not useful) and "CUIT" (useful). So how do I prevent the useless ids to be passed as useful?

This is the code:

```
class ConstanciaInscripcion(FormView):

   def get(self, request):
      return render(request, 'app/constancia-inscripcion.html')
   
   def post(self,request):

       form = MonotributoForm(request.POST)
       email = request.POST['Email']

       #Verificar cuit en padron13 una vez que es ingresado
       cuit_r = int(request.POST["CUIT"])
       response = get_persona(cuit_r)
       
       try:
           nombre = response["persona"]["nombre"]
           apellido = response["persona"]["apellido"]
           cuit = response["persona"]["tipoClave"]

       except KeyError:
           nombre, apellido = None, None
           print("El CUIT ingresado es incorrecto")

       except TypeError:
           nombre, apellido = None, None
           print("El CUIT ingresado es incorrecto")
       
       except cuit == "CUIL":
           print("it's not a cuit")

       else:
           print(nombre, apellido)
       
           if form.is_valid():
               cuit = form.cleaned_data.get('CUIT')
               email = form.cleaned_data.get('Email')
               cuit.save()
               email.save()
               return render(request, 'app/constancia-inscripcion.html')
   return render(request, 'app/constancia-inscripcion.html')
```

Comment: I'm curious about the `except cuit == "CUIL":` syntax.  My interpreter says *TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed*.  The `cuit == "CUIL"` expression should resolve to a `True`.  I suspect that it just never gets there; I suspect that you only ever throw `KeyError` and `TypeError`.  Can you verify that your `else` clause actually runs (I would expect that you would see the same issue I see)?

Comment: Oh, it does run because I get the name and last name even though the person has a CUIT and not a CUIL. Maybe that's not the way to do it. But basically if I get CUIL instead of CUIT I don't want it to go on and get the name and last name but rather print an error so how do I manage to do this?

Comment: I don't think you'll get a **`TypeError`** from your ***`try....`*** clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how "except" works.  Except catches specific exceptions that are thrown with the "raise" statement.  You need:

```
       try:
           nombre = response["persona"]["nombre"]
           apellido = response["persona"]["apellido"]
           cuit = response["persona"]["tipoClave"]
       
           if cuit != "CUIL":
               print("it's not a cuit")

       except KeyError:
           nombre, apellido = None, None
           print("El CUIT ingresado es incorrecto")

       except TypeError:
           nombre, apellido = None, None
           print("El CUIT ingresado es incorrecto")
...
```